# Is there a less redundant way to load/save an entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

Currently, we have this pattern a lot in our project. Loading an entity and saving it afterwards is a really common task. Is there a more concise and less redundant way in Kotlin?

```
userRepository.findByIdOrNull(1L)?.let {
    userRepository.save(it.apply {
        firstName = "Jon"
        lastName = "Doe"
    })
} ?: throw NoSuchElementException("User not found")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official way to make it more concise that I know of, but you could create an extension function on `JpaRepository` like that:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any, ID : Serializable> JpaRepository<T, ID>.update(id: ID, modify: T.() -> Unit) = findByIdOrNull(id)?.let {
    modify(it)
    saveAndFlush(it)
} ?: throw NoSuchElementException("There is no ${T::class.simpleName} with id $id!")
```

and use it like this:

```
userRepository.update(1L) {
    firstName = "Jon"
    lastName = "Doe"
}
```

This will make the call site really clean and concise.

`update` could of course return `null` instead of throwing the exception. This depends on your use-case.

---

<sub>In case you wonder why I asked and answered this question right away, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).</sub>